# force firefox to crash or trick firefox into thinking it has crashed on windows

Tags: windows-7, firefox, crash, popups

I would like to recreate a situation in which firefox has crashed and brings up a pop-up windows upon relaunch .

The reason being is that I have a program that periodically opens up firefox, does some stuff, then closes firefox.  A user reported an issue where the program opened firefox, firefox crashed, then a pop-up appeared saying firefox crashed. The program was unable to get rid of this popup on its own and the popup prevented the program from opening firefox up again at a later time.  I never saw the pop-up window and am not familiar enough with firefox to guess at what pop-up this was.

I guess there are two things I would like to know:

1. What popup was observed
2. How to recreate the problem

I am running firefox on a windows 7 machine and have tried the 'taskkill /F /PID ' command and killing the firefox process using task manager.  Both of these methods have not cause the desired result.  If there is a registry entry I can add/modify to trick firefox into thinking it has crashed would work as well.

Sorry if there are not many details to go off of.  Any information on the issue would help tremendously!

Comment: Its the prompt to restore the previous session.

Comment: @ramhound: I thought it might be this, but I dont know why that window would persist and why it would stop firefox from opening back up.

Comment: Because it comes up before Firefox.exe is started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install this user style to crash Firefox http://userstyles.org/styles/90455/crash-firefox
which basically sets:

```css
*{display:table!important}
```

Comment: if I install that user style, will it crash firefox every time I run firefox? or will it just crash once?

Comment: You can crash it just once by doing this:
Click Install with Stylish button, click Switch to Edit, click Preview

Comment: You're welcome, good luck!

Comment: No longer available, can anyone suggest an alternative user style for intentional crashing?

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it (actually Mozilla's way)

Go to `about:config` and turn `devtools.chrome.enabled` to `true`

Open Scratchpad with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>

Switch Environment to Browser and run the following snippet

```
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm");
let zero = new ctypes.intptr_t(8);
let badptr = ctypes.cast(zero, ctypes.PointerType(ctypes.int32_t));
badptr.contents;
```

Crash!

Comment: worked perfectly, brings up the crash report on open

Answer (score 2):

This is made by Mozilla themselves:

http://archive.mozilla.org/pub/utilities/crashfirefox-intentionally/crashfirefox.exe

> == crashfirefox-intentionally --
>
> Tool for QA/testers to intentionally crash Firefox in a way that
>   should cause the crash reporter to start.
>
> See https://github.com/bsmedberg/crashfirefox-intentionally for more
>   details.

Comment: This uses `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` so works on Windows only.

Answer (score 1):

**In windows 10** I have just used `Taskkill /IM firefox.exe /F` to *`/F`orcefully* close firefox in a "bad way" (meaning: a chance of data loss i.e. The current tabs & session) which seems to successfully cause the program to display the tab recovery prompt or perform similar action. See `Taskkill /?` for more information.

**In debian linux** I can use `killall -9 firefox` to kill all firefox processes simultaneously since it uses many processes to run. This should produce an identical result.

Answer (score 0):

#### Crash Me Now! (Simple)

A legacy extension, compatible with Waterfox Classic e.g. 56.2.12.

In the [Classic Add-ons Archive](https://github.com/JustOff/ca-archive/):

- caa:addon/crash-me-now-simple
- https://ca-archive.biz.tm/storage/658/658046/crash_me_now_simple-1.0-sm+tb+fx+an.xpi

In the Wayback Machine:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20180731184149/https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/crash-me-now-simple/

Related, in Reddit:

- [A browser should have a kill button. : waterfox](https://www.reddit.com/r/waterfox/comments/crdy2x/a_browser_should_have_a_kill_button/)